# How to use tf.random.uniform and not generate duplicates

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to creare a random list of integer values that rappresent indices for other operation, the problem is that `tf.random.uniform` can generate the same value multiple times, and i don't want this behavious. Is there a way to change it?

```
indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=[size_for_layer_submodel[index], ], minval=0,
                                maxval=size_for_layer[index], dtype=tf.dtypes.int64, seed=seed, name=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is sampling without replacement.

Try something like this.

```
sorted_indices = tf.range(size_for_layer_submodel[index])
shuffled_indices = tf.shuffle(sorted_indices)
```

Comment: Does this solution generate `size_for_layer_submodel[index]` random integer value in range (0,size_for_layer[index])?

Comment: That's the idea but give it a try to be sure.

Comment: `tf.random.shuffle(sorted_indices)` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked specifically for `tf` but Numpy also has a [function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) for this, `np.random.choice`, which might make things cleaner.

Comment: Sorry but i have to use `tf` operations